# absolutely positioned image disappears in chrome

Tags: css, image, absolute

http://www.poda.dreamhosters.com/

See the "Sample Blog Post" area.... there's actually an image there.  But when I applied absolute positioning to it (I want to use css clip), it disappears.
In the inspector I can select the image and see the outline of where it would be.  It doesn't seem to be a z-index issue... I turned off the background colours for all the elements behind it and couldn't see the image.

Help me find the image please....

I'm using a plugin, so I have limited control over the html output unless I want to edit the plugin files... (WordPress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it:

```
#featured_post_widget-2 img {
    /* ... */
    clip: rect(0px, 346px, 162px, 0px);
}
```

instead of:

```
rect(0px,0px,20px,0px);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your clipping. You have set it in a way that it cuts the image off. Try changing it like: `clip: rect(0px,327px,153px,0px);`

Just to remind, the `rect` syntax is: `rect(<top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left>)`